# MFC Automation how to implement RemoveDocument OnCloseDocument

Tags: com, mfc, automation, ole

I have an MFC MDI Application and I am trying to implement Automation with it. I am trying to create a RemoveDocument. How is that done? OnCloseDocument is causing problems. Is there a "standard" for doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You could just send a WM_CLOSE message to the Document's frame.

Edit:  You could try sending it to the document's view instead.  You can get all views that point to a given document by calling:

```
POSITION pos = pDoc->GetFirstViewPosition();
while( pos != NULL )
{
    CView* pView = GetNextView( pos );
}
```

I "think" that should do the trick ...

Comment: What if the document doesn't have a frame?? Tempalte->OpenDocumentFile(Path, FALSE); // <-- False means hidden